# How do I create this bold style math?

Tags: fonts, formatting, symbols, math-operators

What package or command should I use to achieve this (bolded?) style of LaTeX math?

[image]

Instead of this (regular) style. I know the color is gray in this second picture, but the style is completely different.

[image]

Comment: Somewhat close... `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts,bm}
\begin{document}
\[ \bm{\sum_{n=1}^\infty} \]
\end{document}`

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's a group of **bold** math-font glyphs you're looking at. Instead, it appears to be a regular-weight `\sum` symbol produced by the `stix` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{stix} % Times Roman clone
\begin{document} 
$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty $
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like I had installed the STIX fonts years ago and the browser rendered the math with those for my local file! I was able to confirm by right-clicking the math and looking at the MathJax settings. Thanks!

Comment: Aside: The 5th upvote on this answer brought my overall rep count on TeX.SE to exactly **353,353** points. :-)